# how to get scrollTop position of parent window

Tags: javascript, security, iframe

if (window.parent) {
      scrollTop = jQuery(window.parent).scrollTop();
    }

following code from iframe window throws permission denied.

this direct code (not jquery) too.

```
parent.document.body.scrollTop
```

Is it possible to go around this problems? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

For security reasons, it is not possible to access a frame from a different domain.
Even though what you're doing is completely benign, you still can't do it.

However, try changing `document.domain` to be the same (or parent) domain of the parent window (if you know what it is); that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily if they're on different domains, which would appear to be the case if you're getting permission denied errors.

You can get around this if you have access to both pages by using the `document.domain` property.